Mathematical Proof for Atmospheric Pressure in a Non-Viscous, Incompressible Fluid Flowing Through a Tap
I am studying fluid dynamics and encountered a concept that I am struggling to understand fully. We are dealing with a non-viscous, incompressible fluid (like water) flowing steadily through a tap.
My teacher explained that the pressure difference between any two points in the fluid outside the tap (in the stream of water) is zero because the pressure at every point is equal to atmospheric pressure. The reasoning provided was that since the fluid is exposed to the atmosphere, and there are no containing walls, the pressure must be atmospheric everywhere along the flow.
While this argument seems logical, I am not entirely convinced and would like to understand it from a mathematical perspective. I attempted to use the Equation of Continuity and Bernoulli's Equation to derive this result, but my efforts fell short, and I feel like I might be missing something crucial.
What I’m Looking For:
I would greatly appreciate a clear, mathematical proof or explanation that demonstrates why the pressure at every point in the fluid outside the tap is indeed atmospheric. I’m a high school student, and while I am comfortable with basic calculus, I would prefer an explanation that stays within the bounds of high school-level mathematics.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

What do you think the pressure is at the free surface of the jet?  Is the pressure in a non-viscous fluid isotropic (independent of direction)?  Is there any radial flow which requires a pressure gradient in the radial direction>?

1st Question: As said by my teacher, it is atmospheric pressure. But my question is "why" rather than "what"

2nd Question: It depends. If you have a pipe whose cross-sectional area is decreasing then obviously there will be a pressure gradient along the flow of fluid (viscous or otherwise) to accelerate the fluid so that at narrow cross-sections it flows faster (to conserve mass). However if velocity of liquid is constant then there will be no pressure gradient

3rd Question: What do you mean by "radial direction"? Are you refering to the direction of flow of liquid? if yes then by my teachers logic there won't be any (at least in this case)

I will really appreciate some clarification. You can also point to some resources if you think they will help. thanks for you time @ChetMiller :)

The surface of the jet is in contact with the air.   So the liquid  pressure at the surface  must be the same as the air pressure.  The radial direction is perpendicular to the axis.

i can understand why the pressure at surface in liquid will be atmospheric in case of static fluid (imagine a small particle at surface, since its at rest this forces are balanced in vertical direction, drawing FBD proves that Psurface = Patm). Why would that be case in case fluid that is flowing? It is not at rest and also accelarating in this case

It is not accelerating at the jet.

That sounds weird but lets say its true. Aside from points around the source, fluid is moving. Why would there be the pressure atmospheric??

Because it is contacting the atmosphere at atmospheric pressure.  Are you familiar with Newton’s 3rd law of action-reaction?

Water jet achieves atmospheric pressure when it flows with zero acceleration, and then it does not get thinner along the stream. This happens, for example, when the water jet moves horizontally, e.g. from a hole in a water tank. Initially it gets thinner, but then it almost achieves the thinnest cross-section and the thinning does not continue beyond this limit. After that, pressure inside the jet does not change, and is close to atmospheric. But in the section where the jet changes thickness, pressure decreases along the stream.

Your teacher is wrong - fluid being exposed to atmosphere does not imply the fluid has the same pressure. There are many examples, and water jet is one of them. As the water falls down, it gets faster and the jet gets thinner. Assuming negligible viscosity, you can predict pressure at any point of the jet, until it breaks, as function of velocity, from the Bernoulli equation. Pressure in free jet decreases downstream, and at some point, the thin fast jet becomes unstable and breaks into droplets.

@JánLalinský. Thank for the response. I tried explaining to my teacher that the pressure difference isn't always zero, and I even managed to prove it. However, my teacher kept making us solve problems using the same concept and got them all right. But when I tried, I couldn't find the answers because I had too many variables and not enough equations. I'd really appreciate it if you could prove your proposition. This way, I can check if my proof was correct and confirm whether my teacher was mistaken.

Pressure in the tank varies with position already when there is no flow; pressure at the surface level is atmospheric, and increases with depth. When the opening is made in the bottom, water starts moving everywhere in the tank, but only very little, and pressure in the tank still increases with depth.
When the flow is steady, the Bernoulli equation applies. Let's write down the Bernoulli equation for a streamtube 1 that flows near the jet surface, and for a streamtube that flows through the center of the jet:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\rho v_1^2 + p_1 + \rho g h = const,
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2}\rho v_2^2 + p_2 + \rho g h = const,
$$
where in general, $v$ and $p$ are functions of height.
Because both streamtubes start at the still water surface level, the constants are the same, and at height $h$, we have
$$
\frac{1}{2}\rho v_1^2 + p_1  = \frac{1}{2}\rho v_2^2 + p_2 .
$$
This allows the pressure to vary throughout the horizontal cross-section, if speed does.
Cross-section in the jet shrinks with decreasing height, and thus velocity at the surface has a component in horizontal direction, towards the center. The closer the element gets to the center line, the smaller this component is. Thus the water element experiences radial force that pushes it away from the center line and decelerates it. This force can only come from unbalances pressure forces, thus there is a pressure gradient in the cross-section: pressure at the center line is greater than pressure at the jet surface. Of course, this difference may be very small, compared to absolute atmospheric pressure. But often absolute pressure is not relevant, and only differences of pressure are, and then this difference is not so small.
